# pydub accessing the sampling rate(Hz) and the audio signal from an mp3 file

Tags: python, audio, mp3, wav, pydub

Just found out this interesting python package pydub which converts any audio file to mp3, wav, etc.

As far as I have read its documentation, the process is as follows:

1. read the mp3 audio file using from_mp3()
2. creates a wav file using export().

Just curious if there is a way to access the sampling rate and the audio signal(of 1-dimensional array, supposing it is a mono) directly from the mp3 file without converting it to a wav file. I am working on thousands of audio files and it might be expensive to convert all of them to wav file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you aren't interested in the actual audio content of the file, you may be able to use `pydub.utils.mediainfo()`:

```
>>> from pydub.utils import mediainfo
>>> info = mediainfo("/path/to/file.mp3")
>>> print info['sample_rate']
44100
>>> print info['channels']
1
```

This uses avlib's `avprobe` utility, and returns all kinds of info. I suggest giving it a try :)

Should be *much* faster than opening each mp3 using `AudioSegment.from_mp3(…)`

Comment: aside from the sampling rate and identifying if the file is a mono or stereo, i also wanted to get the audio content in the form of an array.How would I do it?

Comment: @bninopaul There is no way to access the audio data without decoding the mp3 – you'll have to use `AudioSegment.from_mp3(…)` to get the audio data. The raw data is an attribute of the `AudioSegment` instance as `my_audio_segment._data`

Comment: in my case, audio._data returns a long string composed of null character "/x00"

Comment: it's a bytestring - most audio starts with lots of zeros (silence at the beginning) - if you want a numeric array you can convert it pretty easily (here's an example where I did it in an EQ filter: https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/effects.py#L200)

Comment: You can do it by method `audio_segment.get_array_of_samples()`
https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown#audiosegmentget_array_of_samples

Answer (score 3):

frame_rate means sample_rate, so you can get like below;

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

filename = "hoge.wav"
myaudio = AudioSegment.from_file(filename)
print(myaudio.frame_rate)
```